# getDuration() of m3u8 streming video file

Tags: android, m3u

i am working with streaming video player application.

I am able to get the video duration of mp4 formate video

But i could not get the video duration of m3u8 video formate url.

```
 Here is the code i have used
vdoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

                public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int percent) {
                    tv_BufferingPercent.setText(" " + percent + "%");
                }
            });
            System.out.println("GET DURATION :"+vdoView.get);
            txtTotalTime.setText(formatDuration(vdoView.getDuration()));
            sbVideoProgress.setMax((int) vdoView.getDuration());

        }
    });
```

i am getting 0 value for getduration() method.

Please help me

Comment: Can share the content of the m3u8 file ? Is it a playlist ?

Comment: @fiddler yeah, it seems to be an m3u file with UTF8 contents: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U

Comment: @Android Looking at the M3U format it seems that the duration is optional - does the m3u8 file you're reading *have* a duration defined?